# ContextualMediaHelper generating a broken link

Tags: contextual-image-delivery

I am installing and configuring CID for DXA on SDL Tridion 9.1 DXA Website and wondering if following the right approach. This is the reference document following for configuring CID-https://manishmehmood.wordpress.com/2018/06/30/installing-contextual-image-delivery-in-web-8-x/.

**My Problem:** Once I did change the BaseMediaHandler to ContextualMediaHandler in unity.config it starts generating the CID scale up link for the image but the  image is not rendering into the browser

Is there any other way to implement CID for DXA . Please suggest the right approach

Plea**se find my troubleshooting steps:**

1. CID micro service installed successfully.
2. Unity config setting is replaced to Contextual.
3. web.config has proper setting for cid-localhost and to handle Contextual Handler.
4. Checked the application log (site.log, cd_client) and don't find anything related to CID
5. Checked the service logs of CID/Content service and don't find any error.
6. Copied the cwd_engine_conf file and change the white-list to allow everything.
7. BinaryData\tcm-162\media not have any image atleast using Contextual handler. 
   8  Browser generating the image path as /cid/scale/1024x311/devdxa-us.xxxxx.com/media/ballon-burner_tcm162-90431.jpg" for CID Mode.
8. For all the logs DEBUG Mode is set.

**Found the below message in CID LOG ONLY ONCE**

ContextConfigurationErrorListener - Error loading configuration contextEngineCustom in configuration jar:file:/C:/SDL/Live/cid/services/cid/udp-context-engine-11.1.0-1056.jar!/cwd_engine_commons_conf.xml : Cannot locate configuration source ${context.configurationFile}

**Generating new error after engine xml change**

ImageTransformationManager - Caught error 'TransformationException:Image format text/html is not supported' whilst transforming image, pathInfo= '/scale/1024x311/devdxa-us.xxxxxx.com/media/bulls-eye_tcm162-90412.JPG'
com.sdl.context.image.api.exception.TransformationException: Image format text/html is not supported

**Please suggest here**

1. Is the cid image generate on the fly which is happening now.
2. Is the steps followed is in the right direction?
3. Is there any exact documentation available on this integration?

Comment: Maybe you’re suffering from this issue? https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-F2114310-F707-4590-AB13-07EADBC7750C

Comment: Hey Rick , already tried out this using the domain name

Comment: To help investigate this please share details such as configuration, errors, and stack traces (with customer-specific information properly redacted or anonymized).

What do you mean by "generating" for the contextual image? What are you calling in your markup/image request parameters and what does the browser console show for the response?

Comment: Hey Alvin, Configuration is same as per the blog link shared in the main thread, troubleshoot site.log, cd_client.log, cid and content service log and find one  DEBUG [main] ContextConfigurationErrorListener - Error loading configuration contextEngineCustom in configuration jar:file:/C:/SDL/Live/cid/services/cid/udp-context-engine-11.1.0-1056.jar!/cwd_engine_commons_conf.xml : Cannot locate configuration source ${context.configurationFile}
 ContextConfigurationFactory - Building context configuration from org.apache.commons.configuration.CombinedConfiguration@674fd531

Comment: "Generating" here refers to the image tag rendered by browser(view source) when contextualimagehandler is set - This is the tag rendered <img src="/cid/scale/1024x311/devdxa-us.xxxxx.com/media/ballon-burner_tcm162-90431.jpg" alt="" data-aspect="3.3" width="100%"/>

Comment: Please update your question with (formatted) error messages and source code, rather than putting those unformatted in comments (the tiny font makes those hard to read for elderly people like me ;-)

Comment: Anyways, there seems to be an issue with your Context Engine’s configuration.